# Repeated regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I parse a strings like :

```
name1="val1"    name2="val2"    name3="val3"
```

I cannot use `split(\s+)` as it can be `name = "val 1"`.
I am doing java but any laguage is okay.

Comment: In what language? Judging by what you have so far, I'm guessing Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is in Java, with a slight variation on the regex, with capturing group to put the name/value pairs into a `Map<String,String>`.

This usage of [`Matcher.find()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) in a `while` loop is typical.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.regex.*;
    //...

    String pattern = "(\\w+)\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*+)\"";

    String text = "name1 = \"val 1\"    name2=\"val2\"    name3=\"val3\"";
    System.out.println(text);
    // name1 = "val 1"    name2="val2"    name3="val3"

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(text);
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println(map);
    // {name3=val3, name1=val 1, name2=val2}
```

#### API links

- [`java.util.Map<K,V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

#### regular-expressions.info links

- [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- [Grouping and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Good answer. I will change `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap`. So it will be printed in the same order.

Answer (score 3):

In Python:

```
import re
astr='''name1="val 1 "    name2 = "val2"    name3="val3"'''
print(re.findall('\w+\s*=\s*".*?"',astr))
# ['name1="val 1 "', 'name2 = "val2"', 'name3="val3"']
```